# Remove top layer from pre-trained model, transfer learning, tensorflow (load_model)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, transfer-learning

I have pre-trained a model (my own saved model) with two classes, which I want to use for transfer learning to train a model with six classes.
I have loaded the pre-trained model into the new training script:

`base_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("base_model_path")`

How can I remove the top/head layer (a conv1D layer) ?

I see that in keras one can use base_model.pop(), and for tf.keras.applications one can simply use `include_top=false`
but is there something similar when using tf.keras and load_model?

(I have tried something like this:

```
for layer in base_model.layers[:-1]:
    layer.trainable = False`
```

and then add it to a new model (?) but I am not sure on how to continue)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

The base model is made up of a simple `Conv1D` network with an output layer with two classes:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

samples = 100
timesteps = 5
features = 2
classes = 2
dummy_x, dummy_y = tf.random.normal((100, 5, 2)), tf.random.uniform((100, 1), maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)

base_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
base_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(5, 2)))
base_model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D())
base_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
base_model.add( tf.keras.layers.Dense(classes, activation='softmax'))

base_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy())
print(base_model.summary())
base_model.fit(dummy_x, dummy_y, batch_size=16, epochs=1)
base_model.save("base_model")
base_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("base_model")
```

```
Model: "sequential_8"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv1d_31 (Conv1D)          (None, 3, 32)             224       
                                                                 
 global_max_pooling1d_13 (Gl  (None, 32)               0         
 obalMaxPooling1D)                                               
                                                                 
 dense_17 (Dense)            (None, 32)                1056      
                                                                 
 dense_18 (Dense)            (None, 2)                 66        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,346
Trainable params: 1,346
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6973
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: base_model/assets
```

The new model is also is made up of a simple `Conv1D` network, but with an output layer with six classes. It also contains all the layers of the `base_model` except the first `Conv1D` layer and the last output layer:

```py
classes = 6
dummy_x, dummy_y = tf.random.normal((100, 5, 2)), tf.random.uniform((100, 1), maxval=6, dtype=tf.int32)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(5, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 2, activation='relu'))
for layer in base_model.layers[1:-1]: # Skip first and last layer
  model.add(layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy())
print(model.summary())
model.fit(dummy_x, dummy_y, batch_size=16, epochs=1)
```

```
Model: "sequential_9"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv1d_32 (Conv1D)          (None, 3, 64)             448       
                                                                 
 conv1d_33 (Conv1D)          (None, 2, 32)             4128      
                                                                 
 global_max_pooling1d_13 (Gl  (None, 32)               0         
 obalMaxPooling1D)                                               
                                                                 
 dense_17 (Dense)            (None, 32)                1056      
                                                                 
 dense_19 (Dense)            (None, 6)                 198       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 5,830
Trainable params: 5,830
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 1.8069
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f90c87a3c50>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
If I were to only skip the last layer of the old model, do you know how I can define /add the input shape into the new model ?

base_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("base_model_path")

new_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
for idx, layer in enumerate(base_model.layers[:-1]):
    layer._name = layer.name + str(idx)
    layer.trainable = False
    new_model.add(layer)

new_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')

Comment: What exactly is your question now? Did my answer not answer your question?

Comment: Yes your answer did answer my question, so thank you so much for the help!
I just got a new error when I tried to train my new model, and it seems to be a problem with the input shape. Since I am not changing the first layers of the model I am not sure how to define input shape, like you did in the first layer you added to the new model.

Comment: Do you want to use the the input shape from your base model for your new model?

Comment: Yes, the shape should be the same. So I thought I wouldn't have to define it.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional5 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, None, 4, 2, 256)

Comment: Oh. Can you post a new question? It is hard to say where the error is coming from

Comment: Yes, sorry I realize it might be too much code to get into here, so I will give it another go myself. Once again,  thank you so much for your help!

Comment: got ValueError: Shape (50, None) must have rank at least 3                                             at these lines                                                                                                                 for layer in source_model.layers[0:-1]:  # Skip last layer
        new_mod.add(layer)"